# mvc3+entity framework+autofac,website take too much memory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, autofac

My website is built with MVC3, Entity Framework, and AutoFac is used as the IoC container. Now a big problem is the w3wp.exe process of the website is taking too much memory. When the website starts, it uses 300M in a little time and the token memory goes up to 1GB. I don't know how to solve it.

**autofac configuration**

```
public static void Initialise ( ) {

    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    builder.Register(c => new DatabaseFactory()).As<IDatabaseFactory>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ActionService>().As<IActionService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleService>().As<IArticleService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<BookmarkService>().As<IBookmarkService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<BuildLogService>().As<IBuildLogService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<NewsService>().As<INewsService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<NewsTopicService>().As<INewsTopicService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QQAuthService>().As<IQQAuthService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionAnswerService>().As<IQuestionAnswerService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionService>().As<IQuestionService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionSupplementService>().As<IQuestionSupplementService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<RoleService>().As<IRoleService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ActionChannelRepository>().As<IActionChannelRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ActionRepository>().As<IActionRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleCategoryRepository>().As<IArticleCategoryRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<ArticleRepository>().As<IArticleRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<BookmarkRepository>().As<IBookmarkRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<BuildLogRepository>().As<IBuildLogRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<NewsCategoryRepository>().As<INewsCategoryRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<NewsRepository>().As<INewsRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<NewsTopicRepository>().As<INewsTopicRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QQAuthRepository>().As<IQQAuthRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionAnswerRepository>().As<IQuestionAnswerRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionRepository>().As<IQuestionRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<QuestionSupplementRepository>().As<IQuestionSupplementRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<RoleRepository>().As<IRoleRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    builder.RegisterType<UserRepository>().As<IUserRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    IContainer container = builder.Build();
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
```

**service define**

```
public class ActionService : IActionService {
    private readonly IActionRepository actionRepository;
    private readonly IActionChannelRepository actionChannelRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitwork;
    private readonly static ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    public ActionService ( IUnitOfWork unitwork, IActionRepository actionRepository, IActionChannelRepository actionChannelRepository ) {
        this.unitwork = unitwork;
        this.actionRepository = actionRepository;
        this.actionChannelRepository = actionChannelRepository;
    }
```

`

```
public class NewsRepository : RepositoryBase<News>, INewsRepository {

    public NewsRepository ( IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory )
        : base(databaseFactory) {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 获取某人的新闻
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<News> GetNewsOfUser ( int userid ) {
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.CreatorID == userid);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 获取某人的新闻
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userid"></param>
    /// <param name="pagesize"></param>
    /// <param name="pageindex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<News> GetNewsOfUser ( int userid, int pagesize, int pageindex ) {
        if (pageindex < 1)
            pageindex = 1;
        int skipCount = ( pageindex - 1 ) * pagesize;
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.CreatorID == userid).OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTime).Skip(skipCount).Take(pagesize);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 分页
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pagesize"></param>
    /// <param name="pageindex"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<News> GetNews ( int pagesize, int pageindex ) {
        if (pageindex < 1)
            pageindex = 1;
        int skipCount = ( pageindex - 1 ) * pagesize;
        return this.DB.News.OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTime).Skip(skipCount).Take(pagesize);
    }

    public int GetNewsCountOfTopic ( int topicid ) {
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.TopicID == topicid).Count();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 获取主题下的文章
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pagesize"></param>
    /// <param name="pageindex"></param>
    /// <param name="topicid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<News> GetNewsByTopic ( int topicid, int pagesize, int pageindex ) {
        if (pageindex < 1)
            pageindex = 1;
        int skipCount = ( pageindex - 1 ) * pagesize;
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.TopicID == topicid)
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTime).Skip(skipCount).Take(pagesize);
    }


    public int GetNewsCountOfCategory ( int categoryid ) {
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.NewsCategories.Select(c => c.ID).Contains(categoryid)).Count();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// 获取分类下的文章
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pagesize"></param>
    /// <param name="pageindex"></param>
    /// <param name="categoryid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<News> GetNewsByCategory ( int categoryid, int pagesize, int pageindex ) {
        if (pageindex < 1)
            pageindex = 1;
        int skipCount = ( pageindex - 1 ) * pagesize;
        return this.DB.News.Where(a => a.NewsCategories.Select(c => c.ID).Contains(categoryid))
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.CreateTime).Skip(skipCount).Take(pagesize);
    }

    public void UpdateViewCount ( int id ) {
        News temp = this.DB.News.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
        if (temp != null)
            temp.PageViewCount += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid you have to track the problem down to a piece or area of code you can show here. The autofac registering of some types won't eat up that much memory i guess.

Comment: Does your `IUnitOfWork` implement `IDisposable`? Your DbContext/ObjectContext may not be disposed after the request.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using any caching?

You can use a memory profiler, like **[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/)**, to see what object are taking up the memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you think the problem is unreleased components, take a look at whitebox: http://whitebox.googlecode.com

It can automatically find most leaks related to use of IoC.